# Dynamics 365-Assigning Resource to a task

Tags: resources, task, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to allocate a resource to a task in Dynamics 365 programmatically. The code is:

```
private static void AssignResourceToTask(XrmServiceContext xrm)
{
    Guid TaskId = new Guid("e0bdf7c7-6a14-e711-8114-e0071b6ac161");
    Guid ResourceId = new Guid("cd01ae07-b9cd-e611-80e7-c4346bac0910");
    Guid ProjectId = new Guid("7982feea-a0f2-e611-8130-e0071b6a92f1");

    var AssignResource = new msdyn_resourceassignment
    {
        msdyn_resourceassignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        msdyn_bookableresourceid = new Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference("bookableresource", ResourceId),
        msdyn_taskid = new Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference("msdyn_projecttask", TaskId),
        msdyn_projectid = new Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference("msdyn_project", ProjectId),
    };

    AssignResource.msdyn_bookableresourceid.Name = "Amy Alberts";
    xrm.AddObject(AssignResource);
    xrm.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I am unable to assign a resource to a task using the above code.

Comment: What exactly happens? An exception is thrown? Is the Resource Assignment element created in CRM? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but for sure you are not assigning anything, assigning means changing the owner. You are not changing the owner simply creating a record of Resource Assignment which is related to specific project, task and bookable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.AssignRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.assignrequest.aspx)? Your code would look like:

```
_serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
_service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;

var assignRequest = new AssignRequest
{
    Assignee = new EntityReference("contact", ResourceId),
    Target = new EntityReference("task", TaskId)
};

_service.Execute(assignRequest);
```

Microsoft have an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309540.aspx).